# Call RESTful WebAPI from a Chrome Web App

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am working on a Chrome Web App.  It interacts with Google Cloud Messaging.  My question is can the Chrome Web App html5 pages call a RESTful WebAPI service?  I am not finding any examples on how to do this inside the app pages?  The WebAPI will return JSON.  Any tips - very much appreciated.

**Edit**:

This is in the html page:

```html
<body>    
  <select id="ParametersDropDownList"></select>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
```

And this is in my test.js file:

```html
var uri = 'http://localhost/custom.webapi/api/parameter?emailaddress=john@foo.bar';
var msg;    
$.getJSON(uri)
    .done(function(data) {
        var appenddata;
        $.each(data, function(key, item) {
            appenddata += "<option value = '" + item.ParameterName + " '>" + item.ParameterName + " </option>";
        });
        $('#ParametersDropDownList').html(appenddata);            
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        var error = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
        msg = "Failed to get action data Error message is " + error.message;            
    });
```

This code works in a regular html5 page.  Meaning, the webapi returns json and the dropdown list is populated with the expected values.

Comment: Do regular forms and AJAX requests not work? Do you get a Cross-Domain error? Please attempt this using normal methods and tell us the error? Where is the API?

Comment: I also think that Google Apps Scripts has a way to do this

Comment: I'm not seeing any traffic. Also not seeing anything through fiddler. Not sure if I need to do anything special with the Chrome Web app.

Comment: Can you post the script you use to access said API?

Comment: @ytppillai - I added additional information to the question.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: What is the error? JavaScript console?

Comment: If `localhost` can't be reached, try hosting on a port forwarded IP, or, better, on an actual website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was CSP related.  Specifically accessing jquery from googleapis.com.  I instead downloaded the minified version and added it to the project.